# Incorrectly selected data in the query

Tags: graphql

Only articles that contain the EmailMarketing tag are needed.

I'm probably doing the wrong search on the tag, since it's an array of values, not a single object, but I don't know how to do it right, I'm just learning graphql. Any help would be appreciated

query:

```
query {
  enArticles {
    title
    previewText
    tags(where: {name: "EmailMarketing"}){
      name
    }
  }
}
```

result:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "enArticles": [
            {
                "title": "title1",
                "previewText": "previewText1",
                "tags": [
                    {
                        "name": "EmailMarketing"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Personalization"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Advertising_campaign"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "title": "title2",
                "previewText": "previewText2",
                "tags": [
                    {
                        "name": "Marketing_strategy"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Marketing"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Marketing_campaign"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "title": "article 12",
                "previewText": "article12",
                "tags": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: This really depends on the API you are querying. Is this a Hasura database, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you first need to have coded an *equality operator* within your GraphQL schema. There's a good explanation of that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37981802/3368818).

Once you add an equality operator - say, for example *_eq* - you can use it something like this:

```
query {
  enArticles {
    title
    previewText
    tags(where: {name: {_eq: "EmailMarketing"}}){
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Specifically, you would need to create a filter and resolver.

The example [here](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/graphql-search-and-filter-how-to-search-and-filter-results-with-graphql/) may help.