# How to use _like with '%' in a graphql string?

Tags: flutter, graphql

I'm using flutter with graphql/client library.
I'm trying to create a string for a gql query that has a where condition:

```
const getUsers = """
query getUsers(\$nameToSearch: String!) {
   users(where: {name: {_ilike: %\$nameToSearch%}}) {
      id
      name
   }
}
""";
```

the problem is that I don't know how to insert the '%' symbol in that string... the example is wrong and I tried all the combinations.
Online I found only basic examples that doesn't use the '%' symbol

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: I think the  question is more relate to `graphql` and you may find answer from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37981269/how-to-search-string-values-in-graphql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37981269/how-to-search-string-values-in-graphql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just store you value inside another variable and then use that variable with ${variable} inside the graphql query it will help you

Comment: I would like to use the 'variables' parameter in query options to pass the variables to avoid injections... at the moment i solved building the string in the classic way but I'm pretty sure that it isn't the correct way